# Edit Column SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript

So I'm changing a SharePoint column from multiple lines of text to single and I don't want to change any other data that is previously inputted already until they go back in and try to change. I'm changing it so there is w character limit....any suggestions or help?

Comment: what is question, do you want to know about what happend to charater limits if change from multi line to single text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the column type to single line you will lose all richness and new lines. There are three things I see that you can do:

1. Change the column type and just lose all the richness and new lines immediately.
2. Add a new single line text column and fill it with the text from the current column, and hide the current column. This will hold your old values but no one will see them and you can remove it later.
3. Add javascript to your form to check the length of text in your multiline and cancel input after your limit.

Comment: I changed it from a multiline to a single and it reverted to the Unicode "&#160" then changed back to rich text and it kept the coding so I have to fix my changes then I'm going to follow the JavaScript way.